Highschool Math Problem About Exponentials $\frac{10}{1-10^{x-y}}+\frac{10}{1-10^{y-x}}$
So the problem goes:
Solve
$\frac{10}{1-10^{x-y}}+\frac{10}{1-10^{y-x}}$
I tried rationalizing but it got really complicated and I couldn't do much with it...
The answer is 10.
I hope someone can explain me how it is solved, thanks.

It seems that a component is missing from the equation. In order to "solve" an equation then there should be an equal sign used. With two factions only then "simplify" seems more justified.

Write $10^{x - y} = u$. Then $10^{y - x} = 1/u$.

You want to simplify
$$\frac {10}{1 - {10}^{x - y}} + \frac {10}{1 - {10}^{y - x}}.$$
To begin with, we factor the numerator out:
$$10 \cdot \left( \frac {1}{1 - {10}^{x - y}} + \frac {1}{1 - {10}^{y - x}} \right).$$
Let  $x - y = z$ and ${10}^{z} = a$, so ${10}^{y - x} = {10}^{- z} = 1 / a$. We are simplifying
$$10 \cdot \left( \frac {1}{1 - a} + \frac {1}{1 - 1 / a} \right).$$
We know
$$\frac {1}{1 - 1 / a} = \frac {a}{a - 1} = - \frac {a}{1 - a},$$
so
$$\frac {1}{1 - a} + \frac {1}{1 - 1 / a} = \frac {1}{1 - a} - \frac {a}{1 - a} = 1.$$
Finally,
$$\frac {10}{1 - {10}^{x - y}} + \frac {10}{1 - {10}^{y - x}} = 10 \cdot 1 = \boxed {10 \,}.$$
This is as claimed.

You can do something like this: $\dfrac{10}{1-10^{x-y}}=\dfrac{10^{y+1}}{10^y-10^x}$ by multiplying top and bottom with $10^y$.
Then your expression will become $\dfrac{10^{y+1}}{10^y-10^x}+\dfrac{10^{x+1}}{10^x-10^y}=\dfrac{10^{y+1}}{10^y-10^x}-\dfrac{10^{x+1}}{10^y-10^x}$.
You should be able to continue from here by taking common factors.

$\dfrac{10}{1-10^{x-y}} + \dfrac{10}{1-10^{y-x}}$
$\implies \dfrac{10}{1-\dfrac{10^x}{10^y}} + \dfrac{10}{1-\dfrac{10^y}{10^x}}$
$\implies \dfrac{10}{\dfrac{10^x - 10^y}{10^y}} + \dfrac{10}{\dfrac{10^x - 10^y}{10^x}}$
$\implies \dfrac{10×10^y}{10^y - 10^x} + \dfrac{10×10^x}{10^x - 10^y}$
Taking a minus common from the second term
$\implies \dfrac{10×10^y}{10^y - 10^x} -  \dfrac{10×10^x}{10^y - 10^x}$
Now,
$\dfrac{10(10^y-10^x)}{(10^y - 10^x)} = 10$
Cancel the common terms.

Hi, big thanks for the answer, it was really enlightening! I think you did a little typo at the second step writing 10^x - 10^y instead of 10^y - 10^x to the denominator, even though it doesn't really matter just wanted to let you know. Thanks for the solution once again

I hope in your question it is given that $x \neq y$.
$$\frac{10}{1-10^{x-y}} + \frac{10}{1-10^{y-x}} = \frac{10}{1-10^{x-y}}(1-10^{x - y}) = 10$$
